# Simple calculator console application not working

Tags: c++

This code is not working as expected, I created this calculator as a school learning exercise but turns out it doesn't seem to work. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

float getsum (float num1, float num2){
    float total;
    num1 + num2;
    return total;
}
float getdifference (float num1, float num2){
    float difference;
    num1 - num2;
    return difference;
}
float getproduct (float num1, float num2){
    float product;
    num1 * num2;
    return product;
}
float getquotient (float num1, float num2){
    float quotient;
    num2 / num1;
    return quotient;
}

int main()
{
//Declaration of two numbers
    float a, b, ans;
    char x;

  cout << "Enter first number: ";
  cin >> a;
  cout << "Enter operation: ";
  cin >> x;
  cout << "Enter second number: ";
  cin >> b;

    if (x == '+'){
        cout << getsum(a, b);
    } else if (x == '-'){
        cout << getdifference(a, b);
    } else if (x == '*'){
        cout << getproduct (a, b);
    } else if (x == '/'){
        cout << getquotient (a, b);
    }
     else {
        cout << "Invalid operation!";
     }

    return 0;
}
ng users to define the operations
```

It returns a value of 0 in every operation instead of the answers in the functions.

Comment: `float total = num1 + num2;`, ask your professor why if you don't get it.

Comment: Compilers can be very helpful if you ask them: https://godbolt.org/z/vdh8G88Yd . The first warning says `num1 + num2;` doesn't do anything. The second says `total` was not given a value. From that you should be able to put together the rest.

Comment: I don't understand.  There are a **plethora** of simple calculator posts on StackOverflow.  A simple search will reveal a dozen or more methods to implement it.  People should always search first, then use a debugger (or maybe vice-versa).

Answer (score 2):

You didn't assign the value to the variable inside your functions. To fix the issue, you can use this. I just assigned the result of the operation into an output variable.

```
float getsum (float num1, float num2){
    float total;
    total = num1 + num2;
    return total;
}

float getdifference (float num1, float num2){
    float difference;
    difference = num1 - num2;
    return difference;
}

float getproduct (float num1, float num2){
    float product;
    product = num1 * num2;
    return product;
}

float getquotient (float num1, float num2){
    float quotient;
    quotient = num1 / num2;
    return quotient;
}
```